# Remove feature below threshold but keep first and last entry of each group in spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe that looks like this

```
+----+---------+------------------+
|user|timestamp|          distance|
+----+---------+------------------+
|   A|        1|               0.0|
|   A|        2| 36.35191443247001|
|   A|        3|62.550475311048984|
|   A|        4|16.847739134139704|
|   A|        5|17.952563555225684|
|   A|        6|102.41261599024176|
|   A|        7| 95.82221771177366|
|   A|        8|104.63394547709433|
|   A|        9|26.506336419934364|
|   A|       10|157.00039533864333|
|   A|       11| 20.15671111217189|
|   A|       12|21.870381223509487|
|   A|       13|18.137363209583356|
|   A|       14|129.28661000398125|
|   A|       15|163.74993239641088|
|   A|       16| 267.4166754520851|
|   B|       17|               0.0|
|   B|       18|101.20396648774368|
|   B|       19|24.029134761698852|
|   B|       20| 97.04635170538656|
|   B|       21|13.411774011828113|
|   B|       22|14.631128012534537|
|   B|       23| 75.87504358867835|
|   B|       24|19.864402941978202|
|   B|       25|14.797121212341262|
|   B|       26| 10.53739042907292|
|   B|       27|   73.658902219453|
|   B|       28|252.58741644688948|
+----+---------+------------------+
```

I would like to write a function in spark that removes all features that have a distance below a certain value but at the same time keep the first and last feature feature of each `user` group, regardless of the distance threshold. What is the best way to achieve this in spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign row numbers which indicate whether a row is the first/last for that user, and do a filter based on the row numbers and the distances:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'first',    
    F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('user').orderBy('timestamp'))
).withColumn(
    'last', 
    F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('user').orderBy(F.desc('timestamp')))
).filter('first = 1 or last = 1 or distance > 50').drop('first', 'last')

df2.show()
+----+---------+------------------+
|user|timestamp|          distance|
+----+---------+------------------+
|   B|       28|252.58741644688948|
|   B|       27|   73.658902219453|
|   B|       23| 75.87504358867835|
|   B|       20| 97.04635170538656|
|   B|       18|101.20396648774368|
|   B|       17|               0.0|
|   A|       16| 267.4166754520851|
|   A|       15|163.74993239641088|
|   A|       14|129.28661000398125|
|   A|       10|157.00039533864333|
|   A|        8|104.63394547709433|
|   A|        7| 95.82221771177366|
|   A|        6|102.41261599024176|
|   A|        3|62.550475311048984|
|   A|        1|               0.0|
+----+---------+------------------+
```